# Is there a constant describing the minimal Windows FileTime Value in .Net?

Tags: .net, datetime, constants

I am using the DateTime.ToFileTime and FromFileTime methods to store and retrieve timestamps in a database. The mininum windows file time is midnight, Jan 1, 1601. Is there a constant similar to DateTime.MinValue, that describes this value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, but it is simple to create your own:

```
    public static readonly DateTime MinFileTime = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

For people like me searching for the same "min file value" for a `DateTimeOffset`, the definition would be:

```
public static readonly DateTimeOffset MinFileTimeOffset = new DateTimeOffset(MinFileTime);
```

with MinFileTime defined as in Hans' answer..

PS: DateTimeOffset doesn't have a `FromFileTimeUtc` method.